# How to ensure web app uses firebase function emulator with correct URL for testing

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am trying to test a google firebase oncall function so created a basic vue app with google authentication. I added the following line to ensure the emulator was used and I could test locally:

```
firebase.functions().useEmulator("localhost", 5001);
```

I have firebase 8.2.0 in the app and in the functions I have:

```
"firebase-admin": "^8.10.0"
"firebase-functions": "^3.12.0"
```

The app calls the function with the following code:

```
  var callFunction = firebase
    .functions()
    .httpsCallable("myFunction");
  callFunction({
    dataItem: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  })
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

When the function is triggered in the app, the following error is generated:

> index.esm.js?7dc7:490 POST
> http://http//localhost:5001:undefined/myProject/us-central1/myFunction
> net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

The actual URL provided by the emulator:

> http://localhost:5001/myProject/us-central1/myFunction.myFunction

This obviously does not work. How can I clean up this URL?

Comment: If you think there is a bug with the firebase-functions SDK, file it on GitHub.  Note that the latest version is 3.13.0, so you are behind one version.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk

Comment: Ok, thanks. I would think that the bug is on the app side which is running firebase 8.2, as it never seems to communicate with the function due to the URL. Would it make sense to roll anything back?

Comment: @DougStevenson - I moved the app to firebase 8.2.1. I moved firebase-functions on the function project to 3.13. I am now getting a "deadline exceeded" on the app when I call the function. I am not getting any error telling me what URL was called, nor can I see that info in the console.

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure to initialize the app client-side, and try *useFunctionsEmulator:*

```
const app = window.firebase.initializeApp(config)
app.functions().useFunctionsEmulator("http://localhost:5001");
```

Comment: Thank you. It turned out my function name was wrong. I needed httpscallable(functionFileName-function) and not just the function name. Then the following worked:

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.functions().useEmulator("localhost", 5001);

It also worked as you suggested with firebase.functions().useFunctionsEmulator("http://localhost:5001").